# Vue3: how to pass an object from provide to index

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've been using vue.js for a few weeks and I would like to understand how to globally inject  to child components an object coming from the server.

When I try to inject the object using **inject:['user']** to a child component it returns an empty object.

```js
 data() {

    return {

    
        user: []
    }
},
 methods: {


    getLoggedUserData() {

        axios.get('/api/get-user/' + window.auth.id
        ).then(response => {

          this.user = response.data.user;


        });

    }
},
provide: {

 return {

user: this.user
}
},
created() {

    this.getLoggedUserData();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `provide` option should be a function in this case to get access to `this.user` property:

```js
export default {
  provide() {
    return {
      user: this.user
    }
  }
}
```

For descendants to observe any changes to the provided `user`, the parent must only update `user` by subproperty assignment (e.g., `this.user.foo = true`) or by `Object.assign()` (e.g., `Object.assign(this.user, newUserObject)`):

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async getLoggedUserData() {
      const { data: user } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')

      // ❌ Don't do direct assignment, which would overwrite the provided `user` reference that descendants currently have a hold of:
      //this.user = user

      Object.assign(this.user, user) ✅
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-provide-inject-obj?file=src/App.vue)